# Chrome Extension to inject into React Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject some code onto a website using a Chrome Extension.  The website is a React App, and has a specific div that I am targetting.

In my content script, I am doing a simple check and then injecting the content on the page.  I've tried it on server rendered pages with success, but I cannot get it working on the React App.

```
const viewport = document.querySelector('.extension-button');
const app = document.createElement('div');
app.id = 'inject';
viewport.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', app);
```

The code in my extension is as above. If I log out document at the start, I can see the full html code, including the div with class "extension-button".

The problem I have though is that viewport is then null.
If I type the code above into my console on the website, it logs out the div.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Content scripts run before the page script renders the page (dynamically, that's how many modern sites work) so you need to use MutationObserver to detect the exact moment the element is added to DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm So inside my MutationObserver i'd just put the code above and then disconnect it immediately?

Comment: That'll work assuming the React app doesn't recreate the element later.

Comment: No, its part of the initial page thats created when the components mount